# Execute a table with list of bigQuery commands

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I have a table with bigQuery update commands, for example:
Row is: `UPDATE`table`AS t2 SET chr3_3268035_CT=1 FROM`sorted_500`AS t1 WHERE t1.sample_id = t2.sample_id AND t1.PIK3CA_features="chr3_3268035_CT"`

Is there a way to send this table column for execution?
Many thanks!

Comment: I don't understand this question. Are you able to edit/reword it to make it clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly execute commands listed in your table, but you could write a script to read a series of commands from a table and then execute them.